# Java - Factory, Instance

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

```
public class DataFactory {

    class SYNOP implements IDataSources {}
    class WRF implements IDataSources {}

    public abstract class Factory {
        public abstract IDataSources CreateModel();
    }

    public class SYNOPFactory extends Factory {

        @Override
        public IDataSources CreateModel() {
            return new SYNOP();
        }
    }

    public class WRFFactory extends Factory {

        @Override
        public IDataSources CreateModel() {     
            return new WRF();
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Factory factory = new WRFFactory();

    }
}
```

And i got message error like this:

> No enclosing instance of type DataFactory is accessible. Must qualify
>   the allocation with an enclosing instance of type DataFactory (e.g.
>   x.new A() where x is an instance of DataFactory).

What did i do wrong?

Regards

Comment: You are trying to instantiate an inner class which is not `static` from a `static` context. This won't work. You need to mark your nested classes `static` (or instantiate them using an instance of `DataFactory`).

Comment: Or better: Define each class in its own File as intended.

Answer (score 1):

`SYNOPFactory` and  `WRFFactory` are declared as inner class of `DataFactory`.

It means that instances of them require a instance of DataFactory.
You could instantiate them for example  as

```
Factory factory = new DataFactory().new WRFFactory();
```

But in fact, it makes not really sense to make them inner classes.
Why do you would need to couple so tightly instances of them with `DataFactory` ?

You should rather declare them in their own class file.
And extract also other classes in their own classes. Otherwise you would have the same problem.

---

Note that if you want to hide `IDataSources` implementations from client, you could declare subclasses of them as private class member of the factory subclass that creates instances of them :

```
public class SYNOPFactory extends Factory {

    private class SYNOP implements IDataSources {
    }

    @Override
    public IDataSources CreateModel() {
       return new SYNOP();
    }
}

public class WRFFactory extends Factory {

    private class WRF implements IDataSources {
    }

    @Override
    public IDataSources CreateModel() {
       return new WRF();
    }
}
```

In this way, this will compile fine as you program by interface :

```
Factory factory = new WRFFactory();
IDataSources dateSources = factory.CreateModel();
```

But this will not as now `WRF` is private to the `WRFFactory` class :

```
WRF wrf = new ...;
```

---

Note also that it is not required to create multiple instances of a factory.
And repeating the `new DataFactory()` idiom will finish by creating many factory instances.

A factory may create multiple instances of objects but why would you need to have multiple instances of a factory ? 
A single one can create all objects you need.
So you should have a singleton instance of the factory.
To achieve it, you can use the singleton DP or the dependency injection (that is better).

Dependency injection requires a DI framework.
 You don't seem to use it.
As workaround, in plain java, you could implement a eager Singleton (thanks Bill Pugh) such as :

```
public class WRFFactory extends Factory {

    private class WRF implements IDataSources {
    }

    private static WRFFactory instance = new WRFFactory();

    private WRFFactory(){
    }

    public static WRFFactory getInstance(){
       return instance;
    }
    @Override
    public IDataSources CreateModel() {
       return new WRF();
    }
}
```

Now, you can create your `IDataSources`   instances in this way :

```
IDataSources datasources = WRFFactory.getInstance().CreateModel();
```

Comment: If I declare them in own classes, i can still use pattern factory?

Comment: Of course......

Comment: Ok but now i am trying divide my factory to own classes, and i am doing this like that: SYNOPFactory in own file, and Factory(abstract class in other file), example public class SYNOPFactory extends Factory {
 
 @Override
 public IDataSources CreateModel() {
  return new SYNOP();
 }
} I get error like this No enclosing instance of type DataFactory is available due to some intermediate constructor invocation

Comment: "You should rather declare them in their own class file.
And extract also other classes in their own classes. Otherwise you would have the same problem."

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i am doing this like that:

File IDataSources.java

```
package pl.weatherPrediction.interfaces;

public interface IDataSources {
    //void getFiles(String url, String folder, String timeStamp);
}
```

File Factory.java

```
package pl.weatherPrediction.factory;

import pl.weatherPrediction.interfaces.*;

public abstract class Factory {
    public abstract IDataSources CreateModel();
}
```

File SYNOPFactory.java

```
package pl.weatherPrediction.factory;

import pl.weatherPrediction.factory.Factory;
import pl.weatherPrediction.interfaces.IDataSources;

public class SYNOPFactory extends Factory {

class SYNOP implements IDataSources {}

@Override
public IDataSources CreateModel() {
    return new SYNOP();
}
```

}

File WRFFactory.java

```
package pl.weatherPrediction.factory;

import pl.weatherPrediction.interfaces.IDataSources;

public class WRFFactory extends Factory {

    class WRF implements IDataSources {}

    @Override
    public IDataSources CreateModel() {     
        return new WRF();
    }       
}
```

File Main.java

```
package pl.weatherPrediction.App;

import pl.weatherPrediction.factory.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Factory factory = new SYNOPFactory();
        factory.CreateModel();

        factory = new WRFFactory();
        factory.CreateModel();

    }
}
```

Is that correct @davidxxx?

Comment: It is rather fine. Just the way of instantiating factory subclasses should be improved. I updated my answer to explain this point.

Comment: Yes, yes i am reading your hints now @davidxxx :)

Comment: I updated with a simple and efficient singleton implementation. But note that in "real" projects, a dependency injection facility should be favored over this classical implementation.

Comment: Ok so your implementation for singleton in this case will be better than this?

Comment: The singleton will be more simple (not need to handle himself the singleton instantiation/retrieval) and more flexible. See SpringFramework for example : https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/

Answer (score 0):

You need the object

`private static DataFactory dataFactory;`

You need a private Constructor

```
    private DataFactory() {
}
```

And you need an instance builder

```
    public static DataFactory getInstance() {

    if (DataFactory.dataFactory == null) {
        DataFactory.dataFactory = new DataFactory();

    }

    return DataFactory.dataFactory;

}
```

Then you call it in main

```
DataFactory dataFactory = DataFactory.getInstance();
```

This is a true factory Class